# Restrict Shape Re-sizing on spreadsheetgear

Tags: vb.net, excel, spreadsheetgear

Is there any way by which I can remove anchors of a shape added in spreadsheetgear. So that the user cannot change the size of the shape. Please Suggest a solution or any work around.

Answer (score 1):

You could enable worksheet protection on the sheet that contains the shapes you want to lock.  This involves using one of the following:

- IWorksheet.[ProtectContents](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet~ProtectContents.html) - set to true
- IWorksheet.[Protect](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet~Protect.html)(...) - enables [ProtectContents](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet~ProtectContents.html) but also requires a password to unprotect (using the IWorksheet.[Unprotect](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet~Unprotect.html)(...) method)

You will also need to ensure that your IShape's [Locked](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Shapes.IShape~Locked.html) property is also set to true.  Otherwise, this protection mechanism will not be enforced for your shapes.  Note that this feature will disable more than just changing the size of a shape--it basically locks out any modification of the shape.

Also note that this protection mechanism will also disable many other modifying capabilities for your worksheet, such as editing cells whose IRange.[Locked](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Locked.html) property is set to true, resizing row/column headers, modifying AutoFilter options, etc.

Comment: In short you can say that it will lock every thing on my sheet, as I have tried it as well. Actually I am creating a prototype in which I was supposed to read the borders of cell as lines(top, left, height and width). So I decided to draw a line instead of border so that it could be easy to read it. But the mentioned problem is there with lines. Although with your previous help I am able to do a lot with spreadsheetgear, so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround has been found from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752280/how-to-add-a-triangle-marker-to-any-cell-corner-of-spreadsheetgear-grid). I added an event of workbook which is available with the name `ShapeSelectionChanging`. A single line of code `e.Cancel = True` worked for it. But still a problem is that the anchors are being shown for a while. Tell me if anyone have any suggestion.